# Removing h1 tags

Tags: laravel, tinymce

I'm using tinymce in my laravel site and when I select a word and give it a heading 1 it gets saved to the database with the h1 tag and if I display it on my site then I get < h1 > Heading  instead of Heading being the h1 style.

Is there a way to remove this but still keep the style?

Comment: While printing, make sure that you use {!! !!} instead of {{ }}

Comment: show the data, which is stored in database

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you use {!! !!} instead of {{ }} while printng on view.

More info:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<?php echo $your_data; ?>
```

instead.
Laravel using `{{}}` bracket to avoid attacked from hacker via script by insert code in search bar. But you must check your data before print it out.